# Category is not showing when email is sent using graph api - Microsoft

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to send email adding category in the email like Confidential,Restricted etc. I have first used the draft message api to draft the email and it is working fine ,I can see cateory in draft but when trying to send that draft message , email is getting sent without category.Below are the apis I am using

To draft the message - POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/mailFolders/{id}/messages
To send draft message - POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/send

Please help if there is any other way to add the category and send email using graph api.

P.S. - I have also added required api permission (Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.Send)

I am expecting to send emails with category using graph api

Answer (score 0):

Message categories are stored in a MAPI property. When message is sent, it is converted to MIME and the property is left behind. Even if the message is sent between two mailboxes on the same Exchange server without being converted to MIME, categories are never copied - they are never transmitted.

Comment: Then how we can send category in email via graph api , is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: You don't. You cannot send a category from Outlook, and you cannot force your category on the recipient in Graph.

Comment: Is there any way to send sensitivity labels like Internal,Restricted,Confidential in email via graph api ?

Comment: Sensitivity labels are different from categories, they are designed to be sent with the message (the message itself becomes encrypted). You can list labels defined in the org, but I don't think you can set them on a message being sent. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/security-sensitivitylabel?view=graph-rest-beta